# Presta shop meta tag on homepage issue

Tags: php, prestashop

While there are meta tag for description and keywords on each page in PRESTA SHOP but it is not showing on index page itself only. If someone has faced similar problem and have figured it out then kindly help me out.

Regards

Comment: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/ is probably a better spot for this

Comment: I read the forums but not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Back Office > Preferences > SEO & URLs. U can edit meta tags for index.php page here. Easy:). Hope this helps.

Comment: no. this is the basic and everyone can do it. The problem is it is not showing for index page only. Hope you understand the problem.